# Moving mouse position then back to beginning position

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to make keys move the mouse to a different position on the screen and then instantly back, at a very fast rate (50+ times per second) This is my current Code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
POINT p;

for( ; ; )
{

if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x57) < 0)
{
    GetCursorPos(&p);
    std::cout << "W key pressed";           
    SetCursorPos(0, 0);
    SetCursorPos(p.x, p.y);
    Sleep(100);
}
}
```

With this code it'll just change my mouse position then update as to where it was (I don't have free movement of my mouse and just keeps it at/around 0,0) If I put Sleep(100) at the end then it works pretty consistently but every ~10 seconds my mouse will get stuck at 0,0 again, the more I put up the sleep the less this happens, but why?

*edit* console app in Visual Studio

Comment: Mouse isn't a C++ category. Do you think you should tell more about the OS environment?

Comment: What framework are you using? Because the code you give, is not valid C++. Provide a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking, as those will help you get more and better answers from the community. This appears to be Windows executable, the `GetAsyncKeyState` is likely being "pushed" back on its stack, and making too many calls. The function would then yield and keep a temporary value, that waits to be refreshed. [As per documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx) you should not rely on the function call, to ensure changes

Comment: How would I get around this using something other than GetAsyncKeyState then?

Answer (score 0):

See documentation for [GetAsyncKeyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Return value
>
> Type: SHORT
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value specifies whether the key
>   was pressed since the last call to GetAsyncKeyState, and whether the
>   key is currently up or down. If the most significant bit is set, the
>   key is down, and if the least significant bit is set, the key was
>   pressed after the previous call to GetAsyncKeyState. However, you
>   should not rely on this last behavior; for more information, see the
>   Remarks.

Example

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState('W') & 0x8000)
{
    std::cout << "W key pressed\n";
}
```

`SetCursorPos(0,0)` moves the cursor to top-left corner, while `SetCursorPos(p.x, p.y)` moves the cursor back to where it was when you called `GetCursorPos`. You won't see any changes to the mouse position.

It is not common to use these WinAPI functions in a console program.